# SwiftUI State is not working at all in my app

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to add some SwiftUI code to my existing app, which was built with UIKit. It is iOS 13+ so SwiftUI should be supported. However running the following code does not update the state at all when running it. I also tried several other examples from websites, but the state is not updating at all.

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var index = 0

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Index: \(self.index)")
        
        Button("increment") {
            self.index += 1
        }
    }

  }
}
```

The weird thing is that this code works and updates state when I created a brand-new Xcode project. Is there some Xcode setting I need to change for SwiftUI to work properly in my existing project?

Comment: It seems like there isn't any issue with `SwiftUI` code. The issue could be in the code which is showing the SwiftUI View or there could be some view on top of this view which can be found out using `View Debugger`.

Comment: Would you show how did you integrate SwiftUI view into UIKit view?

Comment: I just created a new Xcode project and transferred all of my files and dependencies over (very tedious). SwiftUI now works  with state with the exact same code. There must have been something wrong my my Xcode proj file.